# Change multiple classes with getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to find the answer to what I think should be an easy fix but I must be looking over something. I'm very new to Javascript and not comfortable with jQuery. Also I am wanting to do this entirely in javascript as this is my 1st real attempt with it. I have a project that uses check boxes and I've had some help getting to where I am but I'm trying to use document.getElementsByClassName to cause a style change to multiple classes.

I've updated my script to the following, using the .querySelectorAll option. I've also added an else to remove the grey text color and enable the check boxes.

```
function bannerBernini() {
if (document.checkForm1.att_2.checked || document.checkForm1.att_5.checked || document.checkForm1.att_6.checked || document.checkForm2.att_9.checked || document.checkForm2.att_15.checked || document.checkForm3.att_23.checked)
{
    var berninis = document.querySelectorAll('.picasso, .matisse');
    for(var i = 0; i < berninis.length; i++) {
    berninis[i].style.color="#d1d1d1";}
    var not_bernini = document.querySelectorAll('#att_3, #att_10, #att_11, #att_13, #att_14, #att_16, #att_17, #att_18, #att_19, #att_20, #att_21, #att_22, #att_24');
    for (var j = 0; j <  not_bernini.length; j++){
    not_bernini[j].disabled=true;}
}
else
{
    var berninis = document.querySelectorAll('.picasso, .matisse');
    for(var i = 0; i < berninis.length; i++) {
     berninis[i].style.color="";}
    var not_bernini = document.querySelectorAll('#att_3, #att_10, #att_11, #att_13, #att_14, #att_16, #att_17, #att_18, #att_19, #att_20, #att_21, #att_22, #att_24');
    for (var j = 0; j <  not_bernini.length; j++){
    not_bernini[j].disabled=false;}
}}
```

**Now I need to figure out how to have check boxes that are shared by 2 of options but not interfere with each other. For instance;

The checkbox 'Single graphic use' only applies to Bernini but the check box 'Silver Finish' applies to both Bernini and Picasso. How do I make that one still enabled when 'Single graphic use' is checked, but not enabled if 'Clip-in Top Rail' is checked?

Here is some of the html if needed

```
<div id="column1" style="width:250px; padding:5px 10px 5px 10px; float:left">
    <form name="checkForm1" id="checkForm1">
        <span class="all"><input type="checkbox" id="att_1" name="att_1" class="all" onChange="">Single-sided</span><br />
        <span class="bernini"><input type="checkbox" id="att_2" name="att_2" onChange="bannerBernini();">Visible Banner: 33.5" x 36"-78.7"</span><br />
        <span class="picasso"><input type="checkbox" id="att_3" name="att_3" onChange="">Medium Duty Spring System</span><br />
        <span class="matisse"><input type="checkbox" id="att_4" name="att_4" onChange="">Clip-in Top Rail</span><br />
        <span class="bernini"><input type="checkbox" id="att_5" name="att_5" onChange="bannerBernini();">Adjustable Twist Locking Pole</span><br />
        <span class="bernini"><input type="checkbox" id="att_6" name="att_6" onChange="bannerBernini();">Single graphic use</span><br />
        <span class="all"><input type="checkbox" id="att_7" name="att_7" onChange="">Carrying case included</span><br />
        <span class="all"><input type="checkbox" id="att_8" name="att_8" onChange="">Silver finish</span><br />
    </form>
```

Thanks for any assistance you can supply.

I've updated code and here is a link to what I have. I'm close to having what I need (MANY THANKS TO EVERYONE) The only thing I can't figure out now is;

The check box 'Tape-in Bottom Rail' needs to display all the check boxes that apply to the 'bernini and picasso' classes. Right now if you click that check box it works. BUT if you also choose a check box that ONLY applies to 'bernini' OR 'picasso' then uncheck it, options become available that shouldn't. Anyone have a suggestion on how to alleviate that?

http://jsfiddle.net/g_borg/48uhn/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `document.getElementsByClassName` use `document.querySelectorAll` and pass in the CSS *selector* (not just the classnames):

```
var berninis = document.querySelectorAll('.picasso, .matisse');
for(var i = 0; i < berninis.length; i++) {
  berninis[i].style.color="#d1d1d1";
}
```

Comment: Be careful with querySelectorAll: http://ejohn.org/blog/thoughts-on-queryselectorall/

Comment: This solution seems to work really well. I've applied this to my code and am able to click the checkbox on and off and looks great.

Comment: @g_borg That's because it's the solution you're looking for ;) The way you use `querySelectorAll` is exactly the way you were trying to use `getElementsByClassName` in the first place.

Comment: Should I in fact worry though with the link that was posted Alex? I did update the code with what HaukurHaf had suggest and this also works. Is this just a case of having multiple solutions and none being better than the other?

Comment: @AlexWeinstein Very valid warning, as it may not be intuitive in the instance John brings up. However, John's critique is based on how he would have thought it to work five years ago. It's implementation makes just as much sense.

Comment: @g_borg No, not for what you've done here. You should still read and understand the article since you're learning. But remember, it was written five years ago and deals with logic of a more library-ish way of finding elements. The article, however, does not apply to your specific case since you're using it on `document` anyway.

Comment: @rgthree I've updated my code above with the queryselector. Which seems to be working well. I also added an else statement that reverts back to the original display if a selection is unchecked. Thanks a ton for your assistance. I'm still trying to get some other parts to work but at least now my code is much cleaner and is starting to function properly with only a few issues left.

Answer (score 3):

To maybe clear up a little more confusion, you *can* have multiple class names in `getElementsByClassName`, but it will select elements having **all** listed classes.

In other words,

```
document.getElementsByClassName('picasso matisse')
```

will select this

```
<span class="picasso matisse"></span>
```

but not these

```
<span class="picasso"></span>
<span class="matisse"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you! That I get, I guess I was misapplying what I had read.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName() only works on one class at a time.

You could change your function so it looks something like this:

```
function bannerBernini()
{
if (document.checkForm1.att_2.checked || document.checkForm1.att_5.checked || document.checkForm1.att_6.checked || document.checkForm2.att_9.checked || document.checkForm2.att_15.checked || document.checkForm3.att_23.checked)
{
    var classes = ['picasso','matisse']
    for (var j = 0; j < classes.length; j++)
    {
    var berninis = document.getElementsByClassName(classes[j]);
    for(var i = 0; i < berninis.length; i++) {
    berninis[i].style.color="#d1d1d1";}
    {
        document.getElementById("Picasso").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Matisse").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("att_3").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_10").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_11").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_13").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_14").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_16").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_17").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_18").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_19").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_20").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_21").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_22").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("att_24").disabled=true;
    }
}}}
```

What I did is that I created an array of classes you want to go through, initilized the array with the two classes you want to use and then we simply iterate through the array.

I'd recommend you try jQuery.  It's easy to use and this kind of stuff is exactly what it was meant for.  Using plain vanilla JS to work with the DOM is sometimes a hassle.

Comment: Wow, I think I "get this". You made a new variable that represents the two classes I am using, then in the getElementsByClassName... placing that new variable instead which covers the 2?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The array I created basically holds both classes you want to manipulate.  We then loop through that array and essentially perform the rest of the code for both of them.  We iterate through the array so in the first iteration classes[j] is 'picasso' and in the next iteratin classes[j] is 'matisse'.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, I tried using this but when I replace my code I get an error on the line that reads var classes = {'picasso','matisse'}. I thought maybe the {} ahould be (), which did remove the error but when I run the page, the style does not change.

Comment: Damn, sorry.  It was a silly error in my code.  The { } braces were supposed to be brackets, [ ].  I've updated my code accordingly.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have to copy-paste "document.getElementById("att_XYZ").disabled=true;" a dozen times is a sign that you have the wrong approach. This is because if you wanted to add another checkbox to your HTML, you would need to morph your Javascript code as well, which is very unpleasant as it causes bugs.

Instead of naming every single element by hand, what I would do is group the elements that need to be controlled at the same time with a single class name. For example:

```
<span class="bernini"><input class="groupA" type="checkbox" id="att_2" name="att_2" onChange="bannerBernini();">Visible Banner: 33.5" x 36"-78.7"</span><br />
<span class="picasso"><input class="groupA" type="checkbox" id="att_3" name="att_3" onChange="">Medium Duty Spring System</span><br />
```

Then, in your code, you could write

```
var allCheckboxesFromGroupA = $('input.groupA');
foreach(allCheckboxesFromGroupA as item) {
   item.disabled = true;
}
```

**EDIT**: if you don't want to use jQuery, the approach still applies:

```
var allCheckboxesFromGroupA = document.getElementsByClassName('groupA');
foreach(allCheckboxesFromGroupA as item) {
   item.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Agree on the copy/paste thing, but note that the OP is not using jquery.

Comment: I would like to use jQurey since I do hear it would make this much easier, but I'm under time constraints and don't really know where to start with it.

Comment: Added a note on how to implement this without jQuery

Comment: Thank you, I do have a question though. Once this project is complete I should have 5 groups e.g. groupA groupB groupC etc, would I then have to make a new var that would list specific groups as a specific group? For instance if I needed to disable groupA and groupB on one chehckbox but groupA and groupC on another?

Comment: For the case when you need to control checkboxes from two different groups, I would add another class to each element - <input type="groupA groupDelta checkbox"..

Comment: I apologize if I'm asking something that I should already know, but if I add the groupA to <input type="groupA checkbox" it is no longer a checkbox, it is now displayed as a text box.

Comment: Sorry, not type="groupA", but class="groupA groupb". Fixed above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two steps. First get the elements with the picasso class and then add the lements with the matisse class to the array:

```
var berninis = document.getElementsByClassName('picasso');
berninis.concat (document.getElementsByClassName('matisse'));
for(var i = 0; i < berninis.length; i++) { // Rest of your code here
```

Comment: Concat does not change berninis value, it returns the new one.

Should be set like 
berninis = berninis.concat (document.getElementsByClassName('matisse'));

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest changing your approach, possibly to the following:

```
function bannerBernini (e){ // e is the 'change' event, passed automagically to the function.
    var _self = this, // the form itself
        changed = e.target, // the changed element
        spans = _self.getElementsByTagName('span'),
        spanClass = e.target.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span' ? e.target.parentNode.className : false,
        children; // a stored variable for later
    // if the span has a className:
    if (spanClass) {
        // iterate over all the spans in the form:
        for (var i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++){
            // if the class of the parent span is *not* in the span we're iterating over:
            if (spans[i].className.indexOf(spanClass) == -1){
                // store the childNodes of the current span in the previously-declared variable:
                children = spans[i].childNodes;
                // iterate over those childNodes:
                for (var c = 0, cL = children.length; c < cL; c++){
                    // if the childnode is an element (nodeType === 1), and is of type == 'checkbox':
                    if (children[c].nodeType === 1 && children[c].type == 'checkbox') {
                        // set the current checkbox/childNode's disabled attribute to true, or false (the checked-state of the changed element):
                        children[c].disabled = changed.checked;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// the form we want to act upon:
var form = document.getElementById('checkForm1');

// adding an event-listener and binding an event-handler (for that event):
form.addEventListener('change', bannerBernini);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aM5Gf/1/).

In up-to-date browsers, though, the above can be shortened considerably to:

```
function bannerBernini(e) { // again the event ('e') passed automagically
    // the className of the parent span element to the changed element:
    var filterClass = e.target.parentNode.className;
    // if we have a filterClass:
    if (filterClass) {
        /* we're using array.prototype.forEach to iterate over the collection
           returned by "document.querySelectorAll('span')", the 'a' represents
           the array element we're iterating over currently: */
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('span'), function(a){
            /* setting the disabled property of the (first/only) input of
               type="checkbox" to:
               false, if the filterClass is 'all',
                   or the classList of 'a' contains the filterClass *and*
               the changed-element is now checked. */
            a.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').disabled = !(filterClass === 'all' || a.classList.contains(filterClass)) && e.target.checked;
        });
    }
}

var form = document.getElementById('checkForm1');

form.addEventListener('change', bannerBernini);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aM5Gf/2/).

Comment: David, this code is great, going to make my head explode though. I looked at the JS Fiddle demo and it works great but there is one thing that I need to do along with the disabling and style change of elements. I notice that if you choose 2 of the orange check boxes for instance, the other colors become disabled as it supposed to happen. But if you un-check one of the orange boxes, all of the other check boxes become enabled again. Is there a way to control that?

Comment: I assumed that's what you would want? Can you (clearly) explain your specific requirements?

Comment: I'll do my best to make this clear (sorry if my terminology is off).

Comment: I'm trying to create a list of check boxes that represent different attributes of 3 different items. As a user selects an attribute, the attributes that do not correspond with each other become disabled and greyed out. Also there are 3 divs with images displaying the items and as users select those attributes, the corresponding div is displayed. That all works as is right now but there are a few attributes that are shared by items. I need to try to get the attributes that apply to an individual item to be active.